# Macbook pro file recovery

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a hard drive from a 2012 macbook pro that no longer boots.  I don't really care about booting from it but I want to copy the files of it.  When I plug it in with my SATA-USB rig.  It seems to know some things about it but won't show me the files.  From browsing help sites I see that knowledgeable people want to see certain info like:

```
Peter-MacBook:~ peterdeklerk$ sudo gpt -r show disk2
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2          4         Pri GPT table
          6  122096635         
  122096641          4         Sec GPT table
  122096645          1         Sec GPT header
```

and

```
Peter-MacBook:~ peterdeklerk$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            499.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Mountain Lion HD        499.1 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Sierra HD              +499.2 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 3D5E3AC4-76A9-4FC7-BBD8-942BBBB4F035
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
```

Is there any hope for recovering these files?  I called one local data recover outfit and they want at least $500!

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Can you see the drive and its partition(s) in DiskUtility?

Comment: I can see the drive but not it's partition in DiskUtility

Comment: First let me say that my depth in this area is not very, and so please don't take my word as final. But, according to `man diskutil`, the `list` option **will** list any partitions it finds. In this case, as your listing shows it above, it seems it has found none. I have to say that IMHO, no partitions = no data. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but that's how it looks from here. I hope I'm wrong - perhaps someone else can add something useful. Do you recall any activity that would have erased this disk?

Comment: Over a period of several months the macbook shut itself down more and more frequently until it would no longer start.  I replaced the hard drive and re-installed macOS.  It still sometimes shuts itself down so I guess there could be two problems.

Comment: The only other things I might add are: 1) [check the HD mfr website for something like this](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=866#macOSlate), and 2) check out some of the SMART software and 3rd party utilities that might offer data recovery.